# How to modify single key value pair with Charles proxy rewrite

Tags: regex, charles-proxy

I would like to modify the value of a single key in a larger json response body using Charles proxy re-write.

As an example, I want to change age from 20 to 30 (but can be any initial value):

```
{
   "userId": "some_value_i_dont_want_to_touch",
   "username": "Charlie",
   "age": "20"

}
```

I do not wish to replace the entire json body as that is not practical for my situation; I just want to modify the value of a single key.

The regex `"age":[\s\S]"(.*)"` or `"age":[\s\S]"[^"]+"` highlights the text I want on sites like https://regex101.com/

I've tried a few variants of this as well, but none of them seem to actually change the value.

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOQss.png)

If I just enter the Match value `"20"` and the Replace value as `"30"` it works which tells me I have the url and path correct, but I'd like to avoid accidentally replacing the wrong thing.

Using the current full value without regex doesn't work either, so trying to do `"age": "20"` -> `"age": "30"` doesn't work, but maybe I need to escape something, though this would also limit me to cases where I know the value beforehand which is not ideal.

The error logs also indicate the request was re-written, but nothing changes
Ex: `Running: Body: "age":[\s\S]"(.*)" -> "age": "30"`

I am not clear on how the groups work (with the $) but maybe this has something to do with it.

I am probably just missing something obvious or going about this wrong.
Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For this topic, perhaps there is no whitespace needed because a proxy response is a text string with no spaces, however when we view it in JSON Text it helps us to read(thus having white spaces)

---

For the rest like me who is new that may help!
I just learnt that for `[`  needs to be escaped for regex to work, etc:

Match:
`"xxxx":\[]`     #tick regex

or you may,

`^"xxxx.{0,}"`

- `xxxx` refering to anything that starts with (`^`)
- `"` at the end marks the end of the string or else it'll match everything else

Replace:
`"xxxx":\["new"]`

Hope this helps!